# Cumulative Count in Power BI/DAX

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I have seen many different questions that are similar but nothing that I can find that will work.

I am trying to calculate a "running" total for the amount of support tickets that I had on any given day prior to today. I have a current (today) total queue size, and know for each day whether I added to or removed from that queue.

For example:

| Date | Created < Known | Completed < Known | Growth < Known | Total Size < Unknown |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10-Jan |  |  |  | 100 |
| 09-Jan | 79 | 77 | +2 | 102 |
| 08-Jan | 97 | 92 | +5 | 107 |
| 07-Jan | 64 | 67 | -3 | 104 |
| 06-Jan | 70 | 66 | -4 | 100 |
| 05-Jan | 78 | 80 | +2 | 102 |
| 04-Jan | 90 | 82 | -8 | 94 |
| 03-Jan | 74 | 68 | +6 | 100 |
| 02-Jan | 83 | 87 | -4 | 106 |
| 01-Jan | 80 | 70 | +10 | 116 |

10-Jan is the only known Total value. The remainder total values are being calculated.

In Excel, this would be a simple formula D3 = D2 + C3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(Calculated column on 'Table' table)
RecursionWithoutIFAndNoFilter_AlsoThisIsWhatIcouldUnderstandFromYourPost_Sorry = 
--RunningGrowth
VAR CurrentDate = 'Table'[Date]
VAR RunningGrowth = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Growth < Known]), REMOVEFILTERS('Table'), 'Table'[Date]>=CurrentDate)
--MAXDateInTable (I suppose this means TODAY)
--A change in level (because of SELECTEDVALUE) would mean there are more than one row with 01/10 
VAR MaxDate = CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[Date]),REMOVEFILTERS('Table'))
VAR TotalSizeInMaxDate = CALCULATE(SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Total Size < Unknown]),REMOVEFILTERS('Table'),'Table'[Date] = MaxDate)
--Result
VAR Result = TotalSizeInMaxDate + RunningGrowth
RETURN Result
```